# fetch() Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to the React Framework. I am trying to fetch data from my Node Backend. The data I fetch keep returning 'Undefined'.

Here's my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 
"react";

function App() {
   const [response, setReponse] = 
   useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
   fetch("http://localhost:5000/api").then(
   res => {res.json()}
   ).then(
    data => {
    console.log({data});
   }
   )
  });
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: what does the  browser `console`  say?

Comment: it should be `res => res.json()` or `res => {return res.json();}`

Comment: `fetch().then(res=> res.json()).then(data => console.log({data})` .... also may be your server doesn't send any response ?

Comment: It returns 'Undefined'

Comment: That `useEffect()` should also have an empty dependency array, othewise it's going to run after every single render, not just after the first.